# How can I use javascript to control the number of photos paginated from my rails model depending on the size of the users screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

If the user is on a mobile phone, why would I want to paginate 24 photos since he has to scroll down to find them anyways and he might click on the 12th photo before ever getting to the 24th photo... and I can just setup an autoscroll at the 12th photo anyways to load more photos. However, if he is on a laptop, I want to paginate all 24 photos.

Or if I am using bootstrap classes, I want lg-2, md-3 sm-4 ... this means to have even rows of photos I must paginate a multiple of 12 photos, either 12 or 24 or 36 etc. But I do not want to do that. Perhaps I just want two rows of photos (either 12 or 8 or 6).

Is there anyway to achieve this with Rails?

Is it possible with javascript or a javascript framework? How?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: @sabithpocker Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @sabithpocker ?? :)